# How to evaluate pending transactions which will be executed

Tags: pending-transactions, txpool

When subscribing to the Ethereum mempool I receive all transactions that are pending within the network. I would like to understand how I would be able to evaluate whether a transaction will be mined, and if yes when.

Certainly, this has to do with the gas price of the transaction, yet there are some things I do not understand.

One way to evaluate whether a transaction will be mined could be to order all pending transactions by gas price, and the higher the gas, the more likely a transaction will be mined. Yet I don't understand "when" to stop ordering the transactions. As the web socket sends tx hashes continuously, how can I know when it is too late for a tx to be included in the next block?

In other words, I am trying to understand what is the best way to intercept mempool transactions which will be executed in the subsequent block.